# Simple timer event loop

Tags: c, timer, libuv

**The usecase**

I'm writing a C program which needs multiple timers. I had first written a fast prototype which started a `pthread` for every timer. Just a simple `while`-loop with a `sleep` command because 1 second resolution is enough.

But with more than 10 timers it's not a very efficient nor production grade code quality. Therefore I wanted to use an eventloop. I've read several times about libuv and thought to give it a try.

So my idea was simple. Have 1 timer thread which runs the timer eventloop and add and remove timers on the fly. The timers are very simple countdown timers which execute a function pointer when they reach 0 and which can be canceled. So no repetition is needed.

**The problem**

I think the real problem here is documentation, the libuv docs simply aren't very clear on how to achieve this. So I think the code I currently have is rubbish. Let me walk you through it.

At the beginning of my program I'm starting a phtread with the following entrypoint:

```
static void* _uv_loop_thread_entry_point(void *args)
{
    /* Initialize the timer event loop */
    timer_event_loop = malloc(sizeof(uv_loop_t));
    uv_loop_init(timer_event_loop);

    /* Keep running the eventloop */
    while(uv_run(timer_event_loop, UV_RUN_DEFAULT) == 0) {
        /* Wait 1 second for new handles */
        sleep(1);
    };

    /* The timer event loop has stopped, free all resources */
    uv_loop_close(timer_event_loop);
    free(timer_event_loop);

    return NULL;
}
```

Than whenever I want to use a timer I would do the following:

```
uv_timer_init(timer_event_loop, uv_timer);
uv_timer_start(uv_timer, timeout_ms, ??);
```

Now I have several questions:

1. How to use the timer without repetition
2. Where do I set the callback function for this timer
3. How can I know how much time is left in this timer

I can really use some help on this subject.

**Update 1**

Ok, I'm making some progress and it basically works. The libuv event loop runs in a separate thread. And to already answer some of my questions:

1. When the last argument in `uv_timer_start` is 0 the timer will not repeat itself.
2. The callback for the timer timeout event is the second argument of `uv_timer_start`

I don't yet know the best answer to my third question. But for now I keep track of the time when my timer has started and the current time and take the difference. I than substract the difference from the total time of the timer to know how long it will take before the timer will end.

I would still like to know if my `uv_run` implementation is correct.

Kind regards,
Daan

Comment: You talk about pthreads, which are very well documented, but use libuv. So you don't use pthreads in the first place. Use pthreads and your documentation problem will be solved.

Comment: How is `timer_event_loop` defined?

Comment: It's a pointer in the top of the C  file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are playing in undefined behavior territory. libuv is not thread-safe [see the docs here](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/design.html#the-i-o-loop) So while running the loop in a thread is ok, creating a timer in another thread while the loop is running is not.

You can still do it by using a `uv_async_t` handle and a semaphore: `uv_async_send` is thread-safe, so you would call it from the outside, stop the loop and signal a semaphore. The calling thread would wait until the semaphore is signaled. At this point the loop is stopped, so it's ok to create a new timer and add it.

There is no API to know how much time a timer has left.

If all you need is a loop to control some timers libuv might be overkill. You could use [timerfd](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html) if you're on Linux, or a hand-built event loop which only does timers on top of select for example.

Comment: Thank you very much I have written an eventloop with epoll and timerfd, it's now thread-safe and works without the libuv overhead.